# How ensure correct update if assembly Company name changed?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

My VS-2019 .NET application **successfully** upgrades all user's settings on each version change - there is no problem at all.

But due to my application had been acquired by other company, the **COMPANY field of the assembly info must change** and since MSI installs settings on */AppData/Company/Product/Version* I will face the problem of loose the entire user's settings (almost 50 items). Technically speaking, even using:

```
MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default.UpdateSettings = false;
MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

... since COMPANY had changed, this code will be innefective to upgrade the settings from the old company folder to the newer one.

Is there any way to seamlessly migrate the settings between different companies?

If I write a new folder (the new company) with the same settings BEFORE the version/company change, would the newest version locate and upgrade it correctly without any impact?

I appreciate any help on it.

Comment: I think you could have a try to add a new folder to check if it works for you. If it updates failed, Maybe that you need to create a new MSI installer for it.

Comment: That's the problem Jack... I need to keep the "update" function for dozens of users, ensuring that the custom individual settings will be preserved. A new MSI drives to a new "empty" configuration and it will be a huge problem.